# Laravel - Fetching an array from MongoDB collection in laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Want to fetch array on laravel, The Document is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b030a1b5085321e84006eff"),
    "name" : "Amalendu kar",
    "Information" : {
            "email" : "amalkar@gmail.com",
            "comment" : "Ok",
            "website" : "example.com",
            "info" : {
                    "x" : 203,
                    "y" : 102
            },
            "versions" : [
                    "0.9.7",
                    "0.9.8",
                    "0.9.9"
            ]
    },
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-05-21T18:04:11Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-21T18:04:11Z")
```

}

and i ausing this command to save this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'website' => 'required',
        'comment' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
    ]);

    //Data::insert($request->all());
    Data::create(['name' => $request->input('name'),
        "Information"=>[              
            "email" => $request->input('email'),
            "comment" => $request->input('comment'),
            'website' =>$request->input('website'),
            "info" => (object)array( "x" => 203, "y" => 102),
            "versions" => array("0.9.7", "0.9.8", "0.9.9")
        ]
    ]);

    return redirect('/') ->with( 'success', ' Done! ');
}
```

Now i want to fetch 'name' field and 'email' from Infromation here is the code but i am getting error.

```
@foreach ($data as $value)   
    <h1>{{ $value->name }}</h1>
    {{$content[] = $value->Information }}  
    @foreach ($content as $key)
        <h1>{{ $key->email }}</h1>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Getting this error

```
"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string,
```

Comment: Which library do you use to connect Laravel and MongoDB?

Comment: i am using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: Check my answer if it was not enough, say me to explain more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working this way only

```
@foreach ($data as $value )
    <h1>{{$value['name']}}</h1>
    <p>{{ $value->Information['email'] }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: sorry, I have but not getting how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Laravel-MongoDb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) library, use eloquent methods to fetch the data as a collection like below:

```
$data = Data::where('name',$value)->first();
return $data->name; // must return name
return $data->information['email']; // must return email
```

Also if you want to get Information as a collection too, you must define relationships or convert to collection yourself with the Laravel `collect(array)` method.

It must be OK.

Also, try indexes in the bracket in your code as below,

```
@foreach ($data as $value)   
    <h1>{{ $value['name'] }}</h1>
    {{$content[] = $value['Information'] }}  
    @foreach ($content as $key)
        <h1>{{ $key['email'] }}</h1>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Not working. I am fetching all the entire collection $data = Data::all();